# Joining anomalous intervals from different groups using interval distance rather than cell distance

Tags: r

I have a large data frame that has zones that I am trying to join, within groups, where the distance between intervals (not the distance between cells) is less than a given amount. Below is a basic example.

This data frame has two groups (GRP1 and GRP2) in the 'Group' column and zones defined by a binary value in the 'Zones' column, for intervals defined by from and to values (in the 'From' and 'To' columns). I need to join 'Zones' with a value of 1, within 'Groups' by replacing 0's with 1's where the difference in interval between Zones is equal to or less than 1 unit (i.e. the distance between 'To' and 'From' columns with values of 1 is equal to or less than 1 unit).

For example, in the data frame below, Sample.ID's 13 and 14 should have their 'Zone' values of 0 replaced with 1's. The reason being that they fall in between Sample.ID 12 and Sample.ID 15 which both have Zone values of 1, both belong to the same group (i.e. GRP2) with a distance equal to 1 (i.e. Sample.ID 12 'To' value = 14 and Sample.ID 15 From Value = 15).

Sample.ID's 6 and 7 would have 'Zone' values which would remain 0 as the interval distance between Sample.ID 5 and 8 is greater than 1, and Sample.ID 3 would also remain as a 0 as Sample.ID 4 is from a different 'Group'

```
   Sample.ID Groups From   To Zones
1          1   GRP1  2.0  3.0     1
2          2   GRP1  3.0  4.0     1
3          3   GRP2  4.0  5.0     0
4          4   GRP2  5.0  6.0     1
5          5   GRP2  6.0  7.0     1
6          6   GRP2  7.0  8.0     0
7          7   GRP2  8.0  9.0     0
8          8   GRP2  9.0 10.0     1
9          9   GRP2 10.0 11.0     1
10        10   GRP2 11.0 12.0     1
11        11   GRP2 12.0 13.0     1
12        12   GRP2 13.0 14.0     1
13        13   GRP2 14.0 14.3     0
14        14   GRP2 14.3 15.0     0
15        15   GRP2 15.0 16.0     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do this using a custom function.

```
library(dplyr)

change_to_1 <- function(From, To, Zones) {
  #Get index where zone = 0
  inds <- which(Zones == 0)
  #Differentiate separate instances of 0's
  all_0_pairs <- split(inds, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(inds) > 1)))
  #Change the Zone values to 1 where the difference is less than 1
  #and 0-index is not present in first or last row. 
  Zones[unlist(Filter(function(i) {
      if(all(between(i, 2, length(Zones) - 1)))
         (From[i[length(i)] + 1] - To[i[1] - 1]) <= 1
      else
         FALSE
  }, all_0_pairs))] <- 1
  return(Zones)
}
```

Then apply this function to each group.

```
df %>% group_by(Groups) %>% mutate(New_zone = change_to_1(From, To, Zones))


#   Sample.ID Groups  From    To Zones New_zone
#       <int> <fct>  <dbl> <dbl> <int>    <dbl>
# 1         1 GRP1     2     3       1        1
# 2         2 GRP1     3     4       1        1
# 3         3 GRP2     4     5       0        0
# 4         4 GRP2     5     6       1        1
# 5         5 GRP2     6     7       1        1
# 6         6 GRP2     7     8       0        0
# 7         7 GRP2     8     9       0        0
# 8         8 GRP2     9    10       1        1
# 9         9 GRP2    10    11       1        1
#10        10 GRP2    11    12       1        1
#11        11 GRP2    12    13       1        1
#12        12 GRP2    13    14       1        1
#13        13 GRP2    14    14.3     0        1
#14        14 GRP2    14.3  15       0        1
#15        15 GRP2    15    16       1        1
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Sample.ID = 1:15, Groups = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("GRP1", 
"GRP2"), class = "factor"), From = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 14.3, 15), To = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
11, 12, 13, 14, 14.3, 15, 16), Zones = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

Answer (score 1):

A rolling join option using `data.table`:

```
DT[, newZones := Zones]
DT[Zones==0L, lastTo := DT[Zones==1L][.SD, on=.(Groups, To=From), roll=Inf, x.To]]
DT[Zones==0L, firstFrom := DT[Zones==1L][.SD, on=.(Groups, From=To), roll=-Inf, x.From]]
DT[Zones==0L & firstFrom - lastTo <= 1, newZones := 1L]
```

output:

```
    SampleID Groups From   To Zones newZones lastTo firstFrom
 1:        1   GRP1  2.0  3.0     1        1     NA        NA
 2:        2   GRP1  3.0  4.0     1        1     NA        NA
 3:        3   GRP2  4.0  5.0     0        0     NA         5
 4:        4   GRP2  5.0  6.0     1        1     NA        NA
 5:        5   GRP2  6.0  7.0     1        1     NA        NA
 6:        6   GRP2  7.0  8.0     0        0      7         9
 7:        7   GRP2  8.0  9.0     0        0      7         9
 8:        8   GRP2  9.0 10.0     1        1     NA        NA
 9:        9   GRP2 10.0 11.0     1        1     NA        NA
10:       10   GRP2 11.0 12.0     1        1     NA        NA
11:       11   GRP2 12.0 13.0     1        1     NA        NA
12:       12   GRP2 13.0 14.0     1        1     NA        NA
13:       13   GRP2 14.0 14.3     0        1     14        15
14:       14   GRP2 14.3 15.0     0        1     14        15
15:       15   GRP2 15.0 16.0     1        1     NA        NA
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("SampleID Groups From   To Zones
1   GRP1  2.0  3.0     1
2   GRP1  3.0  4.0     1
3   GRP2  4.0  5.0     0
4   GRP2  5.0  6.0     1
5   GRP2  6.0  7.0     1
6   GRP2  7.0  8.0     0
7   GRP2  8.0  9.0     0
8   GRP2  9.0 10.0     1
9   GRP2 10.0 11.0     1
10   GRP2 11.0 12.0     1
11   GRP2 12.0 13.0     1
12   GRP2 13.0 14.0     1
13   GRP2 14.0 14.3     0
14   GRP2 14.3 15.0     0
15   GRP2 15.0 16.0     1")
```